# If Statement not work in template in django

Tags: django, if-statement

I've a problem with if statement in a template using Django and Jade (pre-preprocessor).

When submit my form with POST and I've a error, the view return this template with the values, all work fine!! Except the following:

```
select(id='id_{{ afiliado_form.tipo_identificacion.html_name }}',
        name='{{ afiliado_form.tipo_identificacion.html_name }}',
        class='span4')
        {% for id, tipo in afiliado_form.tipo_identificacion.field.choices %}
        {% if afiliado_form.tipo_identificacion.value == id %}
        option(value='{{ id }}',  selected='selected' ) {{ tipo }}
        {% else %}
        option(value='{{ id }}', ) {{ tipo }}
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

In `afiliado_form.tipo_identificacion` I've:

```
(u'', u'---------')
(1L, u'Cedula de ciudadanía')
(2L, u'Nit')
(3L, u'NN')
(4L, u'Pasaporte')
(5L, u'Cedula de extranjeria')
(6L, u'Tarjeta de identidad')
(7L, u'NUIP')
(8L, u'Carnet diplomatico')
```

And `afiliado_form.tipo_identificacion.value` is the value that's sent. But when renderize my template the "if" not work, not selected item!!

Comment: What is the exact contents of `afiliado_form.tipo_identificacion.value`?

Comment: `afiliado_form` is the instance of form for the model afiliado. `tipo_identificacion` is the field in the table that have the value of the form, it can be in range 1 to 8, and `value` is the attribute...

Comment: I know, but what *is* the value? If you printed it, what would it say? (And very importantly, is it an int or a string?)

Comment: Ok, the value of `afiliado_form.tipo_identificacion.value` can be a value between 1 and 8, example, if I choice the option 1, the `if` will be:
    {% if 1 == '' %}
    ...
    {% if 1 == 1 %}
    ...
    {% if 1 == 2 %}
    ...
    {% if 1 == 3 %}
    ...
    {% if 1 == 4 %}
    ...
    {% if 1 == 5 %}
    ...
    {% if 1 == 6 %}
    ...
    {% if 1 == 7 %}
    ...
    {% if 1 == 8 %}
    ...
But doesn't work!!! In the second comparation should be show the option selected!

Comment: Now hold on. a) are you certain that that attribute is indeed a number between 1 and 8? The most likely reason for this problem is that it's not. Try outputting it directly in the template to check. B) if so, are you sure it is an int, and not a string like `"`8"`?

Comment: Yeah! I'm sure, between for in if add a script `alert("{{ afiliado_form.tipo_identificacion.value }}-{{ id }})` and this show the values correctly

Comment: Another question: can you paste the results of the rendered template here?

Comment: The HTML?? Is this
`<select name="afiliado-tipo_identificacion" id="id_afiliado-tipo_identificacion" class="span5">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">Cédula de ciudadanía</option>
<option value="2">Nit</option>
<option value="3">NN</option>
<option value="4">Pasaporte</option>
<option value="5">Cédula de extranjería</option>
<option value="6">Tarjeta de identidad</option>
<option value="7">NUIP</option>
<option value="8">Carnét diplomático</option>
</select>`

Comment: But your `selected="selected"` is right there: `<option value="" selected="selected">`. This is precisely what you would expect if `afiliado_form.tipo_identificacion.value` were `""`.

Comment: Yeah, but when I submit the form and the view return this template with a error this include the POST data, (If before send I choice the option 3 in the select, and submit and this return, the template should be select the option 3 automatically (And do not), the other fields of the form yes

Comment: I really don't understand what you're saying about the error, the POST data, and the form: it sounds like you really haven't described what problem you are having. Can you add `The value is: {{ afiliado_form.tipo_identificacion.value }}` to the template somewhere where it's conspicuous, then edit the resulting HTML into your question? If it says `The value is: 3`, and yet it still is selecting the `""` option, then I would believe that there is a problem with the if statement specifically.

Comment: Yeah, me too... If you have time, you can see the code usign teamviewer if you want.. Thanks for your help!